# Multiplication of 2 variables

Tags: linux, shell, unix, command-line, multiplication

Supposingly I am working on one of my options in my program.
I have a text file which has the below content.

The format is `Title:Author:Price:QtyAvailable:QtySold`, e.g.:

```
Harry Potter - The Half Blood Prince:J.K Rowling:40.30:10:50
The little Red Riding Hood:Dan Lin:40.80:20:10
Harry Potter - The Phoniex:J.K Rowling:50.00:30:20
Harry Potter - The Deathly Hollow:Dan Lin:55.00:33:790
Little Prince:The Prince:15.00:188:9
Lord of The Ring:Johnny Dept:56.80:100:38
```

Below is my function:

```
printf "%-22s %-16s %-14s %-15s %-13s %s\n", "Title", "Author", "Price","Qty Avail.", "Qty Sold", "Total Sales"
grep "$1" BookDB.txt | while IFS=: read Title Author Price QtyAvailable QtySold; do
  printf "%-22s %-16s %-14.2f %-15d %-13d %0.2f\n", "$Title" "$Author" "$Price" "$QtyAvailable" "$QtySold"
done
```

The problem is I need another column which is called Total Sales, computed by multiplying `Price` and `QtySold`. However I have tried different ways such as `$Price * $QtySold` or `$3 * $5` but still the program does not compute it out for me. Which should be the correct method or way to solve this?

Comment: which shell are you using, bash ?

Comment: @Mellowcandle yes I am using bash.

Comment: @andres  Please keep in mind that although you are using bash today, it is extremely good practice to make sure you code is portable sh.  Bash provides some (minor) conveniences, but they should really only be used at the command line.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could use bc like this:

```
printf "%-22s %-16s %-14.2f %-15d %-13d %0.2f %0.2f\n", "$Title" "$Author" "$Price" "$QtyAvailable" "$QtySold" "$(echo $QtySold*$Price | bc)"
```

Comment: it doesnt work i have tried.
it prints out (40.30*50) instead of generating the result of 40.30 * 50. :(

Comment: Sorry, i shouldn't mix zsh and bash. But that will work also in bash. 
`"$(echo $QtySold*$Price | bc)"`

Answer (score 6):

use [(())](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/dblparens.html)

Example:

```
A=5 B=6 echo  $(($A*$B))
30
```

For floating point numbers you should use awk or bc:

```
A=5.5 B=6; echo $A \* $B | bc
A=5.5 B=6;  echo -e "$A\t$B" |  awk '{print $1 * $2}'
```

However, using awk for the entire script is better for your needs:

```
awk -F: 'BEGIN{ printf "%-50s %-16s %-14s %-15s %-13s %s\n",
           "Title", "Author", "Price", "Qty Avail.", "Qty Sold", "Total Sales"}
         $1 ~ search  {printf "%-50s %-16s %12.2f   %13d   %10d  %10.2f\n",
            $1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $3 * $5}' BookDB.txt search=Harry
```

Or if you wish perl, which is a bit shorter:

```
perl -an -F: -s -e 'BEGIN{ printf "%-50s %-16s %-14s %-15s %-13s %s\n", "Title", "Author", "Price", "Qty Avail.", "Qty Sold", "Total Sales"}' \ 
 -e 'printf "%-50s %-16s %12.2f   %13d   %10d  %10.2f\n",@F,$F[2]*$F[4] if /$search/' -- -search=Harry BookDB.txt
```

Comment: tried to compile but it shows this error.

line90L 40.30*50: syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is ".30*50")

below is the line which causes the error.

Comment: printf "%-22s %-16s %-14.2f %-15d %-13d %0.2f\n",
"$Title" "$Author" "$Price" "$QtyAvailable" "$QtySold" $(($Price*$QtySold))

Comment: @Andres: bash doesn't support floating point numbers. At all. For this an external tool must be used.

Answer (score 0):

line=Lord of The Ring:Johnny Dept:56.80:100:38

```
echo $line | awk -F":" '{$6=$3*$5; print "$3*$5="$6}'
```

output:
$3*$5=2158.4